# History of WINE

Tags: history, wine

I will be doing a talk about WINE and how it has changed the situation for new Linux users that come from Windows and how it has matured from the start till know. I have much info already about it and from experience but right now I am looking for the history of how it has evolved in regards to compatibility or better support for video and audio features such as:

- DirectX 9, 10, 11
- Pixel Shading
- Vertex Shader
- Bump Mapping, Tessellation...
- Sound Stereo, 5.1...
- OpenGL supports

And around what version this features happened. Does not matter if they are not complete but at least some support about them. I have already read some links like:

http://wiki.winehq.org/WineHistory

http://wiki.winehq.org/WineReleaseCriteria?action=show&redirect=WineReleasePlan

but still I do not have enough information to tell for example in what version or versions WINE got support for important video/sound features. This is what I am basically looking for but any other info that I can talk about would be good to.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the source for Wine and looking at ChangeLog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [source for Wine](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wine/files/Source/) and take a look at `documentation/ChangeLog.*` files.  They have every change committed for the project.

Comment: No I have not tried that....I will now crawl under a rock for not thinking something so obvious...